# Comando para finalizar o programa

Tags: python, python-3.x

Existe um comando pra finalizar o programa em Python ou só dá para finalizar usando maneiras como essa:

```
print()
```

Comment: Não entendi. `print` não finaliza o programa. O que exatamente você está tentando fazer?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Comment: A função `print()` serve apenas para pular uma linha.

Answer (score 5):

De forma geral o fim do código finaliza a execução, claro que se estiver em uma função chamada só a função será terminada e voltará para quem chamou.

É recomendado deixar a intenção explícita a não ser em códigos muitos triviais, então colocar um `return´ final seria uma boa ideia.

Se quiser parar imediatamente em qualquer ponto pode usar [`sys.exit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit). Não esqueça de importar o módulo `import sys`.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Conceptual.md).